# Git revert all merges from a branch?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Suppose my history look like this:

```
                     (2A)----(2B)------------ [dev-02]
                     /          \
(A)---(B)---(m1)---(C)---(m2)---(m3)---(D)--- [master]
  \         /            /
  (1A)---(1B)---------(1C)------------------- [dev-01]
```

Later, I realize that `dev-01` branch is all wrong, so I want to revert every merges from `dev-01` to `master`, but not from the other branches.

I know that this command will do the trick:

```
$ git revert -m1 <sha_m2> <sha_m1>
```

Or even better with just a single revert commit:

```
$ git revert -nm1 <sha_m2> <sha_m1>
$ git commit -m "Revert all from branch 'dev-01'"
```

The problem is, I don't know how to (programmatically) find merges from branch `dev-01` to `master`. Because this command:

```
$ git log --merges master
```

Show merge from branch `dev-02` too. I know that if I leave Git generate merge message for me (`Merge branch 'd1'`, for example) then I can easily filter branches with some bash script, but what if I didn't do this?

Assume that I never merge `master` back to `dev-01` after the first fork, can I find every merges from branch `dev-01` to `master`? (Or can I revert merges from that branch by other method?)

Comment: Maybe using repeatedly [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)?

Comment: I don't think I would even attempt to do this programmatically as that's too error-prone. What if, for instance, dev-01 itself has a merge from elsewhere coming into it, and the a subsequent merge into master, in which some parts merged in are actually good? What if merge `m3` depends in some way on `m2` and/or `m1`? Other than that, though, to find candidates to inspect, I'd use `git merge-base` on the "interesting" parents, as @VonC suggested. The "interesting" parents are those of each merge found so far.